# How to create galleries for wordpress posts without plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, gallery, woocommerce

I want to create galleries for my posts working like this :

1. I choose pictures in wordpress post-new page and upload them
2. Wordpress creates an array of those images uploaded
3. And finally i use that array and put gallery into my single.php file

Actually woocommerce is using the exact thing as you see in the picture ( sorry i didn't have English wordpress installed )

any suggestions?

[image: screenshot of woocommerce gallery feature]

Comment: By not using plugin you will just have to include all code in your functions.php and it still will be almost the same as creating plugin.

Comment: But there is a way. Just upload images to post. In media uploader (button above main content) if you choose "uploaded to this post" you can see images that are for current post. In single.php you can get all attachments for post. No plugin. Done.

Comment: i see ,is there any way to add multiple images to one post featured image box ? ( like woocommerce does )

Comment: Without plugins - not really. It's not intended to work like that. You can check DB as to how WP stores Featured image.

Comment: so do you know any plugin which works like that? , i don't want the gallery to appear in post content!

Comment: I'm not a fan of plugins. If you use Media library then you don't need to put images in content [maybe I wasn't clear enough]. I usually create repeatable custom fields using Magic fields or ACF.

Comment: that needs much coding i guess, i need a short way , thank you for your answer and time , i appreciate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the default gallery behavior to your need

- Insert a gallery in tour post, it will create a shortcode like

  ```
  [gallery ids="12,45,67,34"]
  ```
- override the default gallery shortcode function to not display it in your post

  ```
  remove_shortcode( 'gallery', 'gallery_shortcode' );
  add_shortcode( 'gallery', 'my_gallery');
  function my_gallery(){
      return '';
  }
  ```
- retrieve an array of images ids

  ```
  $post_content = get_the_content();
  preg_match('/\[gallery.*ids=.(.*).\]/', $post_content, $ids);
  if($ids){
      $array_id = explode(",", $ids[1]);
  }
  ```

Comment: well if gallery is removed from the content then how is that gonna create an array from get_the_content()

Comment: i have found another solution , i upload pictures but i don't click on "put in post" button i mean i just upload them and i don't put them in post content , and it does the thing , do u think it's a reliable solution? i want it for a customer , and i wanna make sure it won't stop working in a newer version of wordpress (in future)

Comment: the gallery is not removed from content, it's just not displayed when the shortcode is interpreted in the loop, so when you call get_content(), the shortcode is still in there.

Comment: I think for a customer, my solution is more reliable, cause they can easily manage the gallery, remove images, change order. and I think it's a bit hackish for a normal user to upload and not validate/insert. I used to do your solution before the new image management in wordpress, and old coustomers calls me each time, beccause they are not sure how it works, they never remember it and don't want to break everything

Comment: Thank you so much , i used your solution and it's working very good , sorry if i asked too many questions :-D

Comment: don't worry, glad it helps